# How do I show that $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $W =\lbrace (a,b,c)^T\in\mathbb{R}^3: a-3b-c=0\rbrace$

Show in two different ways that $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Do I go by this by showing that it is closed under addition, mutiplication, and that there's a $0$-vector in $W$ such that $u+0=u$. I really need help with this one, thanks.

Comment: As your problem asked for two methods, here is a second: note that $W$ is the nullspace of the matrix $[1,-3,-1]$, which is indeed a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You have to show 
1) $O$ vector is in your set
2) The set is closed under addition
3) The set is closed under scalar multiplication.

For your problem, $(0,0,0)$ is in the set, as $0-3.0-0=0$.
2) If (x,y,z) and (a,b,c) are in the spcae, then $(a+x)-3(y+b)-(z+c)=0$ - do you see why?
3) $\alpha(x-3y-z)=\alpha.0=0$, and so the set is closed under scalar multiplication.

Hence this is a subspcae of $\mathbb{R^3}$

Comment: yes I think I see why, thank you very much

Comment: Sorry posted the comment at the wrong place! If you show that it is closed under multiplication, you are done, since the zero vector is zero times $u$. Also $u+u = 2 u$ etc.